# Create New Table EF Code First with Match existing class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have class with the following struct:

```
public class student
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string name {get;set;}
}
```

I use the following configuration on model creation to match table column with class  in the database based on parameter for example I have ,
16_student,17_student,18_student..... all these tables match the student class

```
 public class studentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Models.student>
        {
            public studentConfiguration (string SchoolId)
            {
                this.ToTable(SchoolId + "_student");
            }

        }
```

The previous function work fine with existing Tables , but how i can force the EF to create new table based on new parameter

in the other word i need if i pass parameter not exist let's say schoolId = 55 new table should be created with the name 55_student if not exist

I Enable Automatic migration now and the tables created successfully when it was not exists but the problem now when I add new school with id 56 the previous tables deleted so i can only add one table each time

is there any where to prevent migration from call delete for these tables just create ??

Comment: You want to create a table for every student you have?

Comment: No , actually this is one database for multiple schools each school has it's own tables i'm starting from existing database and build new application using EF codefirst

Comment: You should use a schema per school, not different table names.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a database table with a table that has a name that is composed from several values of variables. You also hava a `DbSet<TEntity>` in your DbContext, and you want to tell entity framework that this `DbSet` is modeled in your database in a table that has this composed name.

Seeing your advanced usage of class `EntityTypeConfiguration` I assume that you know that this is done in function [DbContext.OnModelCreating](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.onmodelcreating%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

The raison d`être of DbContext is to connect your entity framework classes to the actual database that your classes use. The proper way to model your database would be in this class.

Apparently your override of 'DbContext.OnModelCreating' creates a `StudentConfiguration` object. This object will do the actual configuring of the `Student` entity.

You probably will do this for several entities of your database. All these configurations will need similar information. One of them is the name of the table, others could be the maximum length of certain strings, or the precision of decimals etc.

The proper way to do this, is to give your `StudentConfiguration` an object (o an interface) that contains this information. The whole idea is similar to the factory design pattern:

```
interface ISchoolRequirements
{
     public string StudentTableName {get;}
     ... // other items that differ per school
}

class MySchoolRequirements : ISchooRequirements
{
    ... // properties needed to create a StudentTableName

    // the function that composes the StudentTableName from the properties
    private string CreateStudentTableName() {...}

    // implementation of ISchoolRequirements
    public string StudentTableName {get{return this.CreateStudentTableName(); }
}

public class studentConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Models.student>
{
    public studentConfiguration (ISchoolRequirement schoolRequirements)
    {
        this.ToTable(schoolRequirements.StudentTableName);
        ... // other configuration items
    }
}
```

Your `DbContext` with `OnModelCreating`:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    ISchoolRequirements SchoolRequirements {get; set;}

    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // if no school requirements set, use default school requirements:
         ISchoolRequirements schoolRequirement = this.SchoolRequirements ??
             CreateDefaultSchoolRequirements();

         // create the configurations:
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new StudentConfiguration(schoolRequirements));
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TeacherConfiguration(schoolRequirements));
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ClassRoomConfigurations(schoolRequirments));
         ... // etc
    }
}
```

The advantage is that the creator of your DbContext has full control on the naming of the tables, the maximum size of certain strings, the precision of decimals, the type of DateTime etc. If the user of your DbContext does not need this control, some default configuration is used. You could even decide to read this default configuration from a configuration file